# How to run TeamCity's python runner with multiple files?

Tags: python, teamcity, python-unittest

I write unittests in Python using TeamCity Runner.
Up until now all the tests were in same file, and the line of code that ran the tests in main was:

```
unittest.main(testRunner=TeamcityTestRunner())
```

Now, I have several files of tests, and I want the team city runner the run a **suite**. I saw something like:

```
loader = unittest.TestLoader()

suite = loader.loadTestsFromModule(test_something)
suite.addTests(loader.loadTestsFromModule(test_something2))
suite.addTests(loader.loadTestsFromModule(test_something3))

runner = unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2)
result = runner.run(suite)
```

but as you can see in the first code piece, I do not call runner.run() myself but calling a TeamCityTestRunner().

And idea how can I tell TeamCityTestRunner to run a suite of tests (few different files) ?

Comment: Using a command line call to your python scripts should do the trick, no?

Comment: You set a command line runner in TeamCity, and you call python myscript.py, that will call all your tests suites.

Comment: But that is not what I want...I want to be able to do it from the scripts themselves, in case I will have multiple files or a lot of changes - I don't want to change the team city command each time..

Comment: You don't have to change the teamcity command, you just change the python file, that you include in your sources.